# In Power BI / Dax how do I calculate the max of a measure with current visualization filters?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a working measure called [Overall Negative %] which has a definition of:

```
CALCULATE (
COUNTROWS ( Surveys )
    / CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( ALLSELECTED ( Surveys ) ), Surveys[SVRESULT] >= 0 )
    * AVERAGE ( Surveys[Result as negative %] ),
Surveys[SVRESULT] >= 0)
```

This results in the second to last column below and is working as expected.
[image]

I am trying to get the MAX of the [Overall Negative %] measure within a visualization (in this case a table). Ultimately I want to take the [Overall Negative %] and divide it by the MAX([Overall Negative %]) to get a relative ratio.  For example, in the above table the max [Overall Negative %] would be 4.56%.  So I want to divide each row's [Overall Negative %] by 4.56%.  In the image above, the [Relative Impact1] column represents that attempt (it is incorrect).

Because it's a measure, I can't use MAX(), so I have to use MAXX() to calculate the value.  But in doing so, I think I am losing the visualization's filters / context as it iterates over the supplied table.

How do I get the 4.56% value as the max of the visualization and not the max of the overall surveys table?  In addition, I don't want to filter on specific columns because I want to the measure to adjust based on whatever grouping is set by the visualization.  The [Overall Negative %] column adjusts in this manner.

This is a problem I have run into many times (newbie to DAX and power BI)...so a generalized explanation (not just code) would be very helpful if possible.  But of course, just a solution is definitely welcome.  :)

Some of the things I have tried but have yielded incorrect results:

1. Relative Impact1 = MAXX(surveys, [Overall Negative %])
2. Relative Impact1 = MAXX(ALLSELECTED(surveys), [Overall Negative %])
3. Relative Impact1 = MAXX(ALLSELECTED(surveys), [Overall Negative %])